# How to localize/internationalize app icon?

Tags: ios, localization

I know how to localize texts inside the app but I need to add flags to the icon depending on the device’s language.

Is there any way that I can localize the icon so it also appears localized on the store?

I would prefer to avoid uploading several apps.

According to Apple’s documentation, there is a way but I‘m not able to make it work. I would really appreciate if someone could guide me step by step.

> An iOS application should be internationalized and have a language.lproj folder for each language it supports. In addition to providing localized versions of your application’s custom resources, you can also localize your application icons and launch images by placing files with the same name in your language-specific project directories. Even if you provide localized versions, however, you should always include a default version of these files at the top-level of your application bundle. The default version is used in situations where a specific localization is not available. For more information about localized resources, see “Localized Resources in Bundles.”

Comment: App Store information is localised in App Store connect.

Comment: Yes, but if I’m not wrong, you cannot customize the app icon from the dashboard right?